# How to obtain car insurance in the EU if I do not live in any country more than 180 days

Tags: eu, non-residents

I want to live in the UK for 160 days and Sweden for 160 days, remaining days on holiday usually other EU countries.All efforts to obtain advice about car insurance fail as I will not be in any country more than 185 days, how can this be resolved?

Comment: where is your car registered? (what license plates does it have)